# XML Display Overview

Tags: xml

I know very little about XML.  I build reports exported from Quickbooks based in Excel.  The exporting of some reports takes hours, the deletion of zero quantities (which for some reason can't be filtered out from Quickbooks' end) and the calculations that separate the data into the necessary info (e.g. sales for x item from y store between specific dates) means it takes days upon dates to generate the reports.  I can export the data into XML which takes much less time and as far as I'm aware I should be able either populate a database using the XML or display the data in a Web Application but I'm not sure how.  I have seen a lot of tutorials use either Javascript or PHP to do this but I have also seen info about XML DOMs and other things which has confused me a great deal.
TL;DR - could I have a quick overview of just how to choose which data is displayed from xml and how I would display it?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try XPath expressions for selecting the data: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

As for displaying it, it's up to the program you are writing / using.

Comment: So Xpath selects the data and most any program will then display the data from Xpath?

Comment: Typically, you use XPath in the program you are writing to select data from an XML document. If you are using some commercial application, you may want to review their documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of converting XML to HTML for display in a browser is to use XSLT. Oddly, the less people know about programming, the easier they seem to find this (I think that's because to a programmer, it doesn't feel like real programming as they know it). There are plenty of good tutorials on the web.